# Newline-separated xargs

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

Is it possible to make `xargs` use *only* newline as separator? (in bash on Linux and OS X if that matters)

I know `-0` can be used, but it's PITA as not every command supports NUL-delimited output.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish. There may be another way to go about it.

Comment: @Dennis I use it for various things, often in pipeline with grep, sed, very basic awk etc., mostly to parallelize execution.  
`find -print0 -name \*.foo -maxdepth 1 | xargs -0 -P4` is way too much to type compared with `ls *.foo | xargs -P4`.

Comment: Scripts and functions are two excellent ways to reduce typing.

Comment: This is an SO question, isn't it?

Comment: Only upvoted it so that it reaches 69. Nice

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
alias myxargs='perl -p -e "s/\n/\0/;" | xargs -0'
cat nonzerofile | myxargs command
```

should work.

Comment: `tr '\n' '\0'` works too.

Comment: perl is overkill for a single character. `tr` is faster both for the cpu and for your fingers.

Comment: When the only tool you know is radioactive decay, everything looks like a nuclear reactor

Comment: UGH! You want me to use ***perl***? the hell i won't!!!

Answer (score 79):

*GNU xargs* (default on Linux; install `findutils` from MacPorts on OS X to get it) supports [`-d` which lets you specify a custom delimiter](https://archive.is/q7iEX#selection-93.0-107.5) for input, so you can do

```
ls *foo | xargs -d '\n' -P4 foo
```

Comment: I have `alias xxargs="xargs -d '\n'"` in my bashrc. So I can just do things like this: `grep -IRl foo | xxargs sed -i s/foo/bar/g`

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. No need to break out perl. Though `tr` is a good idea too.

Comment: `brew install findutils` and `gxargs` was exactly what I needed on OS X, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

With Bash, I generally prefer to avoid xargs for anything the least bit tricky, in favour of while-read loops.  For your question, `while read -ar LINE; do ...; done` does the job (remember to use array syntax with LINE, e.g., `${LINE[@]}` for the whole line).  This doesn't need any trickery: by default read uses just `\n` as the line terminator character.

I should post a question on SO about the pros & cons of xargs vs. while-read loops... [done!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574134/when-should-xargs-loops-be-preferred-over-while-read-loops)

Comment: This can only emulate `xargs -n1 -d'\n'`, and not the whole `xargs`.

Comment: @HelloWorld - You can bunch arguments together easily enough, so you can simulate `xargs -n$N` as well with only a bit of extra scripting.

Comment: Yes, I'm among the upvoters, it's just a remark worth mentioning.

Comment: This is exactly what I do! Plus, you can use the `read` options, like reading more words in separate variables, or change delimiter with `IFS=' '`.

Comment: Reading the line into an array when you're expecting single lines is overkill at best, but more likely bug-inducing. When Bash reads into an array, it splits input on `$IFS` (normally whitespace), and concatenating the array with `${LINE[*]}` or `${LINE[@]}` does not restore that original whitespace. Using `while read -r line; do ...` is better for most situations, and lowercase variables avoid conflict with built-in/environment variables.

Comment: @HelloWorld If I understand what you are saying, all the answers to use `-d '\n'` will fail if you simply want to package up each line of the file as a single argument to the same command?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ echo "1\n2 3\n4 5 6" | xargs -L1 echo  "#"
# 1
# 2 3
# 4 5 6
```

Comment: Since `echo` is `xarg`'s default command, you can just do `echo "..." | xargs -L1`.

Comment: yes but what if I want each line in the file to be one argument to a single command invocation?

Answer (score 2):

please use the -d option of xargs

> ```
>   --delimiter=delim, -d delim
> ```
>
> Input  items  are terminated by the specified character.  The specified delimiter may be a single character, a C-style character escape such as \n, or an octal or hexadecimal escape code.  Octal and
> hexadecimal escape codes are understood as for the printf command.   Multibyte characters are not supported.  When processing the input, quotes and backslash are not special; every character in  the
> input  is  taken  literally.   The  -d  option disables any end-of-file string, which is treated like any other argument.  You can use this option when the input consists of simply newline-separated
> items, although it is almost always better to design your program to use --null where this is possible.

Example:

```
$ echo 'for arg in "$@"; do echo "arg: <$arg>"; done' > show_args
$ printf "a a\nb b\nc c\n"
a a
b b
c c
$ printf "a a\nb b\nc c\n" | xargs -d '\n' bash show_args
arg: <a a>
arg: <b b>
arg: <c c>
```

Answer (score -3):

What about `cat file | xargs | sed 's/ /\n/ig'` this will convert spaces to newlines, using standard Linux bash tools.

Comment: If `file` contains spaces and newlines, then the result of this command will make it impossible to distinguish between them, which seems to be going in the opposite direction of what this question asks for